# ERROR: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip. hint: See above for output from the failure

Tags: python, pip, package, command, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install google-colab on my command terminal on windows using the command

```
pip install google-colab
```

And I'm receiving an error in return. The error is as follows,

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pandas

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Anyone knows any work around for it? I'm sorry, I'm new to python if i'm doing anything wrong.

I tried different commands upon searching on the internet, and I don't know if they work, but I tried anyways.

```
pip install turtle==0.0.1
```

But it didn't do anything. I also saw it said somewhere that downgrading to python 3.9 would help but is there any solution with python3.10?